# Wizard like DialogFragment-Chain

Tags: android, android-fragments, orientation-changes, android-dialogfragment

Hi fellow Androiddevelopers,

I try to have two DialogFragments in a row, so when the first is cancelled a second one pops up.

Here is what I have so far:

In my Activity I call the following method:

```
void showFirstDialog() {
        // Pass the context to do a callback
        DialogFragment newFragment = ChangeDialogFragment.newInstance(mContext);
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "myFirstDialogTag");
    }
```

In my DialogFragment I have following code to detect that it will be cancelled:

```
@Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            // Use Context to do a callback and inform the Activity that
            // Fragment is cancelled
        ((Activity) mContext).firstDialogCanceled();
        super.onCancel(dialog);
    }
```

Back in my Activity I react on that eventy by starting the second dialog:

```
void firstDialogCanceled {
        DialogFragment newFragment = InformationDialogFragment.newInstance();
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "mySecondDialogTag");
    }
```

This works perfectly as long as I don't have an orientation change on the first dialog. When I have one I get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after
>   onSaveInstanceState

This exceptions is raised on the line "newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "mySecondDialogTag");"

What I thought how I could  fix this problem is to dismiss the first dialog by hand. I tried following:

```
DialogFragment firstFragment = (DialogFragment) getSupportManager().findFragmentByTag("myFirstDialogTag");
firstFragment.dismiss();
```

Again without an orientation change everyhting is working fine. When I have an orientation change while first dialog is on screen I get a NullPointerException on line "firstFragment.dismiss()".

Why is that happening? Why does the FragmentManager forget about my DialogFragment after a orientation change and why can't I just show the second one. Androidreferences say:

> you should use show(FragmentManager, String) or
>   show(FragmentTransaction, String) to add an instance of DialogFragment
>   to your UI, as these keep track of how DialogFragment should remove
>   itself when the dialog is dismissed.

I DO use show, but it is still not working properly.

Any hint is highly appreciated!

Cheers Ali3n

Comment: I can tell you that the times I have encountered "Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState" is because I was trying to do something on the old/destroyed activity instance rather than the newly-created one due to the configuration change.

Comment: You are my hero :) Post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using old instance of the activity in your dialog fragment. I guess you are passing the current activity as `mContext` in `newInstance` method. After a configuration change such as orientation or keyboard, this context object becomes invalid and it is no longer attached to any window.

You can use `getActivity()` method of `FragmentDialog` to get the current activity it lives in.